# Redirect from one html page to another page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created 2 static html pages locally, `demo1.html` and `demo2.html`.

I need to redirect from one page to another pag. Initially I opened my `demo1.html` page (url is file:///D:/app/demo1.html).

Now on clicking a button in this page I want to redirect to `demo2.html`

I tried:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    window.location.href = "/demo2.html";
});
```

but it did not work. What changes I need to make it to work?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: What errors do you get? Did you load jQuery (which seems like overkill for a redirection)?

Comment: Are the two pages in the same place?  Try removing the "/" from your address: "demo2.html";

Comment: Yes ,its in same place, I tried removing "/" did nit work. no action happens. I have loaded jquery and this function is written on ready function

Comment: can you post your demo1.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the / at the begining of your new url.

If you are loading from a file like you said, writing `"/demo2.html"` will map to `file:///d:/demo2.html`

If you write

```
 $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
     window.location.href = "demo2.html";
 });
```

This will map to the same folder where you started your app, that is `file:///D:/app/demo2.html`

Comment: Did not work, it just adds "?" to th url , no redirection happens

Comment: I just tested the code an it works. If is not working for you is because you are not showing the full example. I recommend you that you post the demo1.html code (Maybe you are using another framework????)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#submit').click(function() {
     window.location = '/demo2.html';
 };
```

Comment: Did not work, it just adds "?" to th url , no redirection happens